# BridJ callback from Native to Java: Is it possible that values in native are overriden?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna, bridj

I want to write a Java wrapper to a native library (with BridJ). The method I want to wrap takes a struct of operations (callbacks):

```
typedef struct _operations {
   int (*op1) (int, ...);
   int (*op2) (float, ...);
} operations;

int method(*operations ops);
```

The operations should obviously be written in Java, so `method` calls back to Java space (using BridJ's Callback mechanism).

However, after executing the Java callbacks and returning to `method`, local variables in the C code have changed:

```
int method(*operations ops) {
  void* uselesspointer;
  DbgPrint("useless pointer before callback is %d\n", uselesspointer); 
  // prints x
  // execute callbacks in Java here
  DbgPrint("useless pointer after callback is %d\n", uselesspointer); 
  // prints something different from x
}
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

// see https://github.com/Maxhy/dokany/issues/7 for details

// edit
thats interesting: the offset of useless pointer seems to be constant, in my application the second debug message is always "192" instead of "0"

Comment: If you're not initializing the `uselesspointer`, then it will have whatever value happens to be on the stack at that time.  Granted, said value should not be changed by the callback execution.

Comment: @technomage But the debug output from the link I provided tells me something different. Does "should" mean it is impossible to happen?

Comment: I mean that if the value *is* changed then the callback invocation is not properly preserving the stack.

Comment: @technomage as I can't really fiddle with the stack in Java, that would be an issue with the java<->native library (BridJ) then, right?

Comment: Correct.  The problem would be either in bridj itself or in the FFI library it is using.  I don't know if you can easily hook up a [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) version, but that might help isolate the issue.

Comment: FYI, I'm pretty sure this would work fine with [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp).